# GeoServer WMS/WMTS to Kibana

Tags: geoserver, wms, wmts, kibana

I'm trying to set up GeoServer to serve map data to Kibana. So far I managed to get data from the US national weather service into Kibana so I know the concept is working.

https://www.elastic.co/blog/custom-basemaps-for-region-and-coordinate-maps-in-kibana

Next I installed GeoServer and created a layer with a shapefile as source as per the documentation. The layer shows up fine in the preview but I can't get Kibana to show it.

Now the Kibana documentation is rather lacking when it comes to WMS documentation but I found this in the link above:

> Geoserver / MapServer / ArcGIS Server
>
> A more advanced scenario might have you running your own instance of
>   Geoserver, MapServer, or ArcGIS Server. These software packages may or
>   may not come with geospatial data needed to create basemaps. You might
>   check out our blog post on using a custom Geoserver basemap with
>   Elasticsearch.
>
> To be compatible with Kibana, basemap tiles created with these
>   software packages **must be cached as raster tiles in the Web Mercator
>   (EPSG: 3857) coordinate system.** All of these software packages can
>   publish WMTS services. You can review the ArcGIS Online example above
>   to determine the tilemap.url parameter from WMTSCapabilities documents
>   created by these software packages.

Under layer settings I found `Coordinate Reference Systems` clicked the find button and scrolled until`I found`EPSG:3857`. That alone did not work though.

Upon further investigation it appears shapefiles are also in vector format. (For some reason in the GUI you have to click to store, and then hit the return button to see the text value because the icon has no text overlay.)

Is there any way I can serve my layer as a raster?

My original data is in .kml format. Also if anyone has ever managed to get Kibana show GeoServer data I would love to hear what other steps might be necessary.

Comment: You need to set tile caching on your layer to get a geoserver wmts, which is what kibana requires (not WMS). A shapefile input is not a problem, geoserver creates the image as part of the service

Comment: Thank you. But under edit layer Tile Caching create a cached layer for this layer and enable tile caching for this layer are already enable. Is there something else I need to set? I also noticed the entries under Gridset are different from what Kibana demands.

Comment: Can you add the details of what kibana wants to your question

Comment: The Kibana requirements are in bold in the quote in the opening post. Kibana requires raster tiles with EPSG: 3857 coordinates.

Comment: What about the entries under gridset you mentioned

Comment: Now I've looked at the documentation I can see where your confusion lies, as there appears to be an interchangeable use of the terms WMS/WMTS (both provide images).    if you look at `Customize a single region or coordinate map` it appears that you can just use a WMS, so what happens if you just do that provide the WMS service end point for your service?

Comment: I managed to get all the layers to display in Kibana. The problem is that the visualization I was using appears to have some bugs or require special settings because as soon as I tested with a different type of visualization the layers showed up by simply using localhost:8080/geoserver/wms and a layer name. No special gridset or anything required.